# Is it fine to modify element of a List in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, ienumerable

I have an object say Person as below:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set:}
    public int Age {get; set:}
    public string Name {get; set:}
}
```

Now if I have a list of Person like

```cs
List<Person> listPerson = new List<Person>();
Person p = new Person { Id=1, Age=27, Name="John" };
listPerson.Add(p);
p = new Person { Id=2, Age=28, Name="Joy" };
listPerson.Add(p);
```

Now I want to modify name to Joy for all the items present in the list, so is the below approach fine:

```cs
foreach(var item in listPerson)
{
    item.name="Joy";
}
```

I am not getting any error and the item's value gets changed too but I came across previous posts saying that we can't change IEnumerable using foreach. If the above code approach is wrong then what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: All of those answers which said "it's wrong" didn't provide a way of how to do it correctly? Please link them so that I can downvote these because they are not helpful.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and pay more attention to formatting your posts in future. I've fixed the formatting for this post, but look at the preview and make sure that all code appears as code, but all non-code appears as non-code before posting.

Comment: You can't add to or remove elements from the collection while iterating, since that will throw an error. Modifying the element however is perfectly allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I came across previous posts saying that we can't change IEnumerable using foreach.

And you're not actually doing that.

The list is just a list of references - you're not changing that list of references. You're modifying the objects that those references refer to.

You can think of the list a bit like the houses on a street. The "rule" about modifying a sequence while iterating over it is saying "you can't change which houses are on a street" - but you're not changing which houses are there, you're changing the color of the front door, and that's allowed.